# Bootstrap jquery hidden and shown.bs.modal modal property does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal. I want to get an operation when the modal is switched on and off. But my script code doesn't work at the opening and closing of the modal.

What I want to do is a video in modal. If the modal is off, stop playing the video. If the modal is on, let the video playback begin.

Bootstrap version 3.3.7, jquery version 3.2.1. The hidden.bs.modal and shown.bs.modal methods do not work here.

```
<script>         

    // Test - shown.bs.modal
    $("#arcaVideoModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        alert('Work shown');
    });

     // Test - hidden.bs.modal
    $("#arcaVideoModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        alert('Work hidden');
    });

</script>






// My application code 
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fancybox-show-caption" id="arcaVideoModal" data-toggle="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls>
                            <source src="/Documents/arca-cm18.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Video play
        $("#btn_play").on("click", function () {

            alert("video play");

            var video = $('#video1')[0];
            video.play();
        });


        //video stop
        $("#arcaVideoModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

            alert("hidden video play");

            var video = $('#video1')[0];
            video.pause();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Why does the hidden.bs.modal and shown.bs.modal method not work here? How do I do things in modal when modal is opened and closed in modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. I share the solution below for my friends who may need them after me. **Good coding for everyone.** Thank you so much.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Video play
        $("#btn_play").on("click", function () {
            var video = $('#video1')[0];
            video.play();
        });
    });

</script>

<script>
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        var video = $('#video1')[0];
        video.pause();
    });
</script>
```

Play and pause feature to be triggered to be written in separate script tags. This is a solution to my problem. There may be different solution methods. We love different ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on the window for the event to fire. Then check the `target` of the event to see if it's the corrent modal for your modal to trigger on. When the ID of the modal matches the one you're wanting to do your action on you do your stuff.

```
$(window).on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
   var modal = e.target;
   var $modal = $(modal);
   if($modal.attr('id') == 'arcaVideoModal') {
      do your stuff
   }
});
```

I also suggest that instead of spamming alerts you have to click away that you use `console.log()` and keep an eye on your developer console.

Comment: I know thanks. Console.Log is a much faster solution. Cevap için teşekkürler fakat bir çözüm değil. Thank you for giving me ideas. @Tschallacka